# Caching and loading Data from server on iOS

Tags: ios, json, caching, realm

I'm using realm to cache the JSON response from the server on iOS devices, and when i open the app again, i should show the cached data until the server gives me a new JSON response to load.

I know it should be make the request with the timestamp from last request, to check if there is a new response or not, but this is not implemented yet, The server send me JSON object every time, event if it's not changed.

Now, i'm asking for the best practice to handle the cached response and the response from the server on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON response has a key that identifies each object, the best practice is updating objects using the primary key.

To define primary key your models, override `primaryKey()` class method.

See,
https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys

Then when you caching the responses, you can use `add(update:)` with `update` parameter `true` .  That allows you to just the responses adding to the Realm regardless whether existing or not. You can download the responses every time, then just store it. Realm looks up existing value by the key and updates it. You do not need to care the value exist or not.